# Can't import app in project URL in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I can't import the app in the project (Django rest framework) URL (urls.py) in a Django project. I have done this same scenario in one of my projects in the past.

from appname import views

This is what I need.

When I try to provide the first letter of my app name in the previous project (like from a) it is giving full app name (from appname) but in the new project, it won't get.

I know there have other options to overcome this. But I need to know the reason behind this.

making the project directory as a source directory the only solution for this? If we doing like this is there any problem, while hosting the project on the server?

Please someone help.

I need to import the app view in my project URL.

Answer (score 0):

Its  because its not in same directory of folder, you can use
try `from .models import *`  or from `filename.appname.models import *`